# Get the section name based on a url segment

Tags: url, sections

I'd like to retrieve the name of a section based on a url segment. Normally I would use {{entry.section.name}}, but this doesn't work, since there is no entry available.

I've got this working:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section(craft.request.getSegment(1)).first %}

<h2>{{entry.section.name}}</h2>
```

This means that I first have to get an entry and then reverse retrieve the section it belongs to.

Is there no direct way to get the section name based on a url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean

```
{% set section = craft.sections.getSectionByHandle(craft.request.getSegment(1)) %}
{{ section.name }}
```